# What to use instead of HttpContext.Current in .net 6?

Tags: .net-6.0

I used this in .net 6 but it is not working

```
{
    string PageUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
    
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some/any, er, context about what your application is, where this code is defined, and what "not working" means?  Is [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context) helpful?